# MS Dynamics - permissions on modules

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, erp, dynamics-sl

I am entirely new to MS Dynamics and have inherited an MS Dynamics environment with my new job. I replaced an employee who had sole ownership and knowledge about the Dynamics set up.

So I am slowly going through all the database tables and fields attempting to learn.

I have come across a problem which is, when I attempt to open a Timecard Correction module I get an "You do not have proper access rights for this screen" message.

Would someone kindly describe to me what I must do in order to be able to access this screen using my user account?

Note that I have access to the SQL Server databases. And I could only find a "Database Maintenence" application for Dynamics as well as the end user application.

FYI this is what I see when I open MS Dynamics.....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was privileges in the end - I found a SYSADMIN account and that did the trick!

thanks.

Comment: By SysAdmin I suspect you mean that you added the SQL Server privilege of SysAdmin to your SQL login. If within NAV your user has the SUPER permission you'll be able to access anything.

Answer (score 1):

Does anyone in your organization have access to this?  If so, then you can check that user's privileges and apply them to your own login.  It could be a license issue if no one can access it.  In that case, you may have to contact your Microsoft partner that you purchased NAV from to get proper licensing.  Good luck.